# The color of my object changes when I use Shadow Catcher

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So, I was playing around with the principaled shader and I noticed that when I included a shadow catcher to my scene, it changed the color/texture of my object. How do I fix it or is it a bug?

[image: Without shadow catcher]

[image: With shadow catcher]

Comment: Please show an image of your compositing nodes.

Comment: So, I figure the answer. It's because the first picture there is no plane under the head but the one with the shadow catcher has a plane which I guess reflects the light which brighten the head. My nodes setup is simple, it's principled shader to the material output.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figure the answer. It's because the first picture there is no plane under the head but the one with the shadow catcher has a plane which I guess reflects the light which brighten the head. My nodes setup is simple, it's principled shader to the material output.

Comment: The shadow catcher plane has a normal material like other planes. You can modify it, but the shadow intensity might change.

Comment: You confused me, so yes the shadow catcher plane has a normal material because it is just a plane but the shadow catcher setting you can't modify other than the Ray Visibility settings.

Comment: But I found out, if you deselect all the diffuse, glossy, transmission and volume scatter but leave camera and shadow on. The object won't get affected by reflective light.